# Reactjs hooks setState - how to setState and wait for it to implement and console.log(newState)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, state, setstate

how can I console.log(name) that will print the new state which is "Tom".
is there a way I can wait for the setName() to finish updating the state and then print the new name?
(It was also a question that i've been asking about in an interview for react job, but
*** without using useEffect with [name] ***)

```
export default function SetStateImmediately() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("Dan")

  function onBtnClick() {
    setName("Tom")
    console.log(name)   /* I want that "Tom" will be printed and not "Dan" */
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onBtnClick}>press to change name</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i tried to await for setName() to finish but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use useEffect you can log it's prev value

Like this:

```
 function onBtnClick() {
    setName("Tom");
    setName((prevState) => {
      console.log("name : ", prevState);
      return prevState;
    });
  }
```

and don't wory, it won't cause extra rerendering

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this callback property in setState..

Comment: your welcome, if it's what you were looking for please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

yes, useEffects are firing after the state has been set and hydration of the html. so try:

```
React.useEffect(() => console.log(name), [name])
```

inside your component

So what happens is:

1. new state
2. new html getting rendered
3. console.log(name)

Comment: yes that's right, that was my first answer to the interviwer, 
but he asked me to do it inside the onBtnClick() function... :\

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The `onBtnClick` function is re-created everytime the component renders. It "captures" the value of `name` from the current render cycle.

When the component mounts, `name` is `'Dan'`. This means that the value of `name` inside the current `onBtnClick` function will always be `'Dan'`.

When you set the state to `'Tom'`, React queues a re-render, and when it re-renders the component, it re-creates the `onBtnClick` function as well. In this render cycle, the value of `name` becomes `'Tom'`. So now the function sees the `'Tom'` value of the `name` state.

The only way to log it afterwards is with a `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be:

```js
export default function SetStateImmediately() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("Dan")
  console.log(name)
  function onBtnClick() {
    setName("Tom")
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onBtnClick}>press to change name</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since this component will render again after this state updates, putting it outside the function definition will work as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
async function onBtnClick() {
  await  setName("Tom")
    console.log(name)   
  }
```

You can try this :)

Comment: `setName` does not return a `Promise`, so adding `await` here has no effect

Comment: AliNauman 
https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia
Read this article :)

Comment: Refer to the official documentation please: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#setstate

Nowhere does it say that the `setState` function is async. And like I said, you can try putting an `await` there - it will make no difference.